# What if we do not use MAX function

Tags: sql-server, migration, functions, entity-framework, max

I was supposed to use a script to get the MAX value from a table. It should have looked like this

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @MaxID AS INT
SELECT @MaxID = MAX([Id]) FROM dbo.suggestion
Insert into suggestion
values(@MaxID+ 1, 'value', 1);
END
```

Instead, due to some error, it went like this

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @MaxID AS INT
SELECT @MaxID = [Id] FROM dbo.suggestion
Insert into suggestion
values(@MaxID+ 1, 'value', 1);
END
```

It was working fine till date, due to some other issue when we started drilling down, then it came to light.

I wonder how it worked till date.

If somebody share their knowledge, it would be highly appreciated

TIA

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you get lucky. Your old query would be assigning the variable `@MaxId` to the last result it got from your query (because it was constantly reassigning the variable per result)

```
SELECT [Id] FROM dbo.suggestion
```

If you have an index on just `Id` then it's not unusual for SQL Server to scan that index for you so the last result is the current highest value of `Id`.

Your correction to use `max(Id)` doesn't really fix your problem, the query can give you a result which could lead to a unique index violation. Imagine what happens when two sessions try to run the same code at the same time - they'll get the same `max(Id)` value and therefore try to insert the same `Id` value.

You want to use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead, this will guarantee that unique values are obtained without serializing access to your table (which is what you’d have to do to make your existing solution work).

Comment: It is possible to use the above code without conflicts, but it needs a transaction under `SERIALIZABLE` isolation.

Comment: Ive made that more clear now @Charlieface

Answer (score 3):

A SELECT statement does not have a guaranteed order by unless you ask for it. In the case it works, it fills the variable 'accidentally' with the last value, as that seems for SQL the most efficient way to retrieve the data.
Brent Ozar has a great article about this:

[Link to Brent](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/04/why-ordering-isnt-guaranteed-without-an-order-by/)

Perhaps the stats, indexes or another thing has changed and therefor the order has been changed.
To guarantee to have the highest number you should add an order by:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE @MaxID AS INT;
   SELECT TOP (1) @MaxID = [Id]
   FROM   dbo.suggestion
   ORDER BY [Id] DESC

   INSERT INTO suggestion
   VALUES
   (
      @MaxID + 1,
      'value',
      1
   );
END;
```

Or, even better, have an autonumber like identity for the Id column, so you don't have the need to calculate it yourself.

[Link to identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16)